# SSRS 2008: How to repeat on new page one row of table header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have table with 3 rows of header, and I needed repeat on new page only second row, first and third is not needed in the pages, excepts first page.
If I set the properies "RepeatOnNewPage" in the second row only, SSRS show the error: "The TablixMember must have the same value set for the RepeatOnNewPage property as those following or preceding the dynamic TablixMember"

If I set this property in the all (3) rows of header - all ok, but I need only one :)

How to repeat only second row on new page?

Comment: Can you move these headers to the report's header?

Comment: No, this is not good variant for my report - table is very complicated, and split a header it will be difficult

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure why, but this seemed to work for me.
For your 3 header rows advanced properties,

```
(Static) KeepTogether= false, KeepWithGroup=None, RepeatOnNewPage= TRUE
(Static the one you want) KeepTogether= True, KeepWithGroup=After, RepeatOnNewPage= TRUE
(Static) KeepTogether= false, KeepWithGroup=None, RepeatOnNewPage= TRUE
```

When i tried this with the top and bottom rows repeat on new page False it gave me the error you described. I changed these to true just to try. I expected them to Repeat on new page but they didnt. My first page had all 3 and the rest just had the middle.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: This comment saved my life today :)

Comment: Great example!!

Comment: I have two headers, I want to show first header on every page but not the second one, second one should only be on first page, any help regard this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go at Column Groups
2. Click on the black arrow at the last
3. Select advanced mode.
4. Go at "Row Group"..
5. In row group you will get LOTS of "static", out of which just select TOP MOST
6. Go to properties

   A. For VS: press F4

   B. For report builder... View->Properties
7. In that select for row headers

   a. Fixed Data: True

   b. Keepwithgroup: After

   c. Repeatonpage: True...

   And for main headers

   a. Fixed Data: True

   b. Keepwithgroup: Before

   c. Repeatonpage: True

Comment: Thanks for "click on the little arrow by Column Groups", never would have found that

Answer (score 1):

Set property **RepeatOnNewPage = True** for all rows of table. Select static row from Row Groups window.

You must have to set ***RepeatOnNewPage*** property for all static rows.

If any static row is not set ***RepeatOnNewPage*** property than it dosen't work and give error.

Answer (score 0):

So just to help clarify the answer based on success from working on my table.  When I did the above action on the top-most static row, I got an error message.  My table has three headers that are grouped and all need to be included in the repeatOnNewPage function. In order to successfully run my report, needed to repeat the step for all the static row headers.

*Static (for each row): FixedData = True, Keepwithgroup = After, and RepeatOnNewPage = True*

I also went into Tablix properties and checked both boxes under Row Headers for *Repeat header rows on each page & Keep header visible while scrolling.*

It was a very happy moment when i did not receive an error message after completing this scenario.  good luck.

Comment: not working for me... could you please suggest other option?