# repeating only some group header rows RS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am struggling with getting only some group header rows to repeat on subsequent pages.  I am using the advanced properties to set FixedData, KeepTogether, KeepWithGroup and RepeatOnNewPage.  No combination seems to work.  I need the first three rows to repeat because there is only text.  The next 8 rows contain group totals that I do NOT want to repeat.

I saw this post:
[SSRS 2008: How to repeat on new page one row of table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594094/ssrs-2008-how-to-repeat-on-new-page-one-row-of-table-header)

but it didn't help me. I still get the TablixMember must have the same value set for KeepWithGroup property as those following or preceding the Dynamic TablixMember.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are adding everything inside the group.

When you click on tablix row you see a "Insert Row" . When you click on it you can see a row to be added inside the group and outside the group.If you add the row inside the group(which we do and system does automatically) it repeats for every row. So please add a row saying outside the row and try to add sum of the rows in this column. I had similar problem it did solve.