# RDLC - How can we get Multiple Headers on Every Page?

Tags: rdlc

In Data Table, I've two Headers defined, I know how to show them on every page:
**Advanced** => **Properties** => **Keep** **With** **Group**, etc.

**But** my question is, I just need to show my first Header on every page but not the second one.
*Pic* *Attached.*

[image]

First Header is Green One, Second Header is Blue, want to repeat First but not second.. Please **Help** me out on this..

Comment: I've already refered to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594094/ssrs-2008-how-to-repeat-on-new-page-one-row-of-table-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer of it, finally, what I've done is, I've first deleted my second static row and then I insert a row inside group above, and in row visibility, I've added an expression:

```
     =IIf(RowNumber(nothing)>1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

And It got me covered.